# QML: What happens when anchors.margin and a side margin, like anchors.leftMargin are both set?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to specify anchors for all sides using `anchors.margins`, but set a side anchor, like `anchors.leftMargin` to a different value.

For example:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 100; height: 100
    color: "black"

    Rectangle {
        anchors {
            fill: parent
            leftMargin: 0
            margins: 30
        }
        color: "lime"
    }
}
```

Which shows:

[image]

It seems to work, but is this a feature or a bug waiting to happen? Isn't `margins` a shortcut that sets all side anchor margins and the fact that it works just due to the order in which bindings are evaluated? If someone modifies the code might `anchors.margins` overwrite the `leftMargin` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchors.margins provides the default value for the more specific margin properties. So, what you are doing is safe and supported.

Comment: I had not understood that anchor.margins is the default value. It makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to set side anchors and `anchors.margins` together.

`anchors.margins`, `anchors.leftMargin`, `anchors.topMargin`, `anchors.rightMargin`, and `anchors.bottomMargin` are all separate properties. The default value for all side anchors is `anchors.margins`; assigning `undefined` to a side anchor reverts it to the `anchors.margins` value.